# Access the 2. dimension of a json array (Java)

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this code:

```
String sURL = "https://example.com/json"; //just a string
// Connect to the URL using java's native library
URL url = new URL(sURL);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.connect();

// Convert to a JSON object to print data
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
String names = rootobj.get("names").getAsString(); 
System.out.println(names);
```

How can I access the second level of the array in the second to last line?  "names" ist the first dimension whichs works fine.
In PHP the solution would be

```
$var = json[...][...] //for accessing the second dimension.
```

How is this done in Java? Something like rootobj.get("names/surname") doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the json looks like

Comment: Sure! Like this one here: https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos

In first line it says "0" -> "id"
How can I access the id?

Comment: Remove the `getAsString()`, and treat the names as a new object

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you please specify your answer? Thank you

Comment: I can't see your JSON. Are the names actually a string? Or is it an **array**? If so, why did you get it as a string?

Comment: Ehhmmmmm ... I am not sure. I posted the code above and the lilne "        String names = rootobj.get("names").getAsString(); " seems to work fine as long its an onedimensional access. Eg I can use the line when the json looks like this http://freegeoip.net/json/ (please notice that the elements don't have "a second level". But I need to access the values from two or more levels like the json here: https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I assume you use GSON for JSON processing. If your JSON element is an array, you can simply access its elements using get(index). Sketched here:

```
//Not taking care of possible null values here
JsonObject rootobj = ...
JsonElement elem = rootobj.get("names");
if (elem.isJsonArray()) {
    JsonArray elemArray = elem.getAsJsonArray();

    JsonElement innerElem = elemArray.get(0);
    if (innerElem.isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray innerArray = innerElem.getAsJsonArray();
        //Now you can access the elements using get(..)
        //E.g. innerArray.get(2);
    }
}
```

Of course this is not that nice to read. You could also take a look at [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), which simplifies navigating to specific parts in your JSON documents.

**Update**: 
In the document you referred to, you want to extract which value exactly? The id value of the array elements (according to one of your comments)? This could be done like this for [this](https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos) example here:

```
JsonElement root = jp.parse....
JsonArray rootArray = root.getAsJsonArray(); //Without check whether it is really an array
//By the following you would extract the id 6104546
//Access an other array position if you want the second etc. element
System.out.println(rootArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("id"));
```

Otherwise please explain in more detail what exactly you want (the code you posted does not match with the json examples you refer to).

Comment: I don't know whether you receive an update due to the update of my post. Thus, I updated my post a bit after your upper comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your Github link, your root element is an array, not an object. (And there's no `names` attribute)

So you need

```
root.getAsJsonArray();
```

Then you would loop over the length of this array, and use a `get(i)`, to access a particular object.

From that object, use another get method to access one attribute of it